# Support vector machine with multioutput ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I am stuck on an error when trying to run a multioutput classifier that is using a support vector machine.

The test set `y_train_svm` looks like this:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

I already checked the number of classes through `np.unique(y_train_svm)`, which returned `array([0, 1])`. That should mean that there are actually two classes available?

This is the code for the classifier that returns the error message:

```
svm_clf = SVC(kernel="linear", random_state=42)
multioutput_classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(estimator=svm_clf)
multioutput_classifier.fit(X_train_svm, y_train_svm)
```

> ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Comment: "That should mean that there are actually two classes available?" No, only that your true labels are one hot encoded

Comment: I am a bit confused - is this a multilabel prediction or ..?

Comment: I want to predict the occurance of different species on different locations based on my training data. In the data, almost all species are present on the majority of locations, thus the many 1's in y_train_svm.

So I want every label to be predicted correctly (either 1 or 0).

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the values of your train/test-arrays as integer like `y_train_svm.astype(np.int8)`, then run your training-code where you use `fit()` again.

Comment: Thanks for your input! As far as I can see,  y_train_svm is already of type int8 (indicated by the note at the end of the array), isn't it?

Comment: hmm true, didnt see that at the end... maybe you have a non-numerical value inside X-train?